# ¿Como puedo seleccionar una parte del texto con selenium?

Tags: python, python-3.x, select, selenium, selenium-webdriver

he estado buscando e intentando hacer que selenium me seleccione y borre a partir d la *@*, debido a que es un nombre de usuario y no puede llevar *@*. Mi idea era de copiar y pegar el correo y quitar de la *@* hasta el final, pero me quede atascado y no consigo avanzar. Si alguien me pudiese ayudar estaría muy agradecido. Aquí dejo el código:

```py
        driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\\Users\\meganano202\\Desktop\\MEGA\\bot\\chromedriver.exe')
    driver.get("https://temp-mail.org/es/")
    time.sleep(10)
    driver.get(e6)
    time.sleep(2)
    elem = driver.find_element_by_name("signup_email").send_keys(Keys.CONTROL+ "v")
    time.sleep(4)
    password_elem = driver.find_element_by_id("signup_password").send_keys(e2)
    time.sleep(4)
    user_elem = driver.find_element_by_name("signup_username").send_keys(Keys.CONTROL+ "v")
    user_elem.selection_range('@', END).send_keys(Keys.DELETE)
    time.sleep(2)
    singup_elem = driver.find_element_by_id("signup_submit").click()
    time.sleep(60)
    change_tab.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL+ Keys.SHIFT+ Keys.TAB)
    time.sleep(10)
    tempmail_elem = driver.find_element_by_class_name("arrow-link-ico")
    time.sleep(5)
    tempmail_elem = driver.find_elements_by_link_text("http://Belacam.com/account/confirm_email/").click
    time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: El nombre de usuario es el email ?, o sea,  `email: lucas@algo.com , username : lucas` ??

Comment: exacto, como quiero usar correos temporales, lo único que querría hacer es quitarle desde la _@_ hasta el final

Comment: mm, y el email lo puedes manipular desde python?, se me ocurre que podrías tener una lista con los mails y hacer `split`. el nombre de usuario : `.split('@')[0]`

Comment: claro pero para eso haría falta el nombre de usuario que es lo que quiero sacar del correo, voy a modificar el código para que veas lo que estoy intentando hacer

Answer (score 1):

Por lo que entiendo estás usando el botón de copy to clipboard en temp-mail.
Lo que te recomiendo es que mejor leas el valor del input en una variable y ya de ahí tomes el correo y el usuario:

```
driver.get("https://temp-mail.org/es/")    
emailInput = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input#mail")
email = emailInput.get_attribute('value')
user_name = email.split('@')[0]
```

Comment: Buenas, he probado el código que me ha puesto pero cuando lo ejecuto pasa, literalmente, de él ,es decir, va todo bien y cuando llega a el `.split` se lo salta y no lo selecciona

Comment: corregido, como es un input no siempre tiene su valor con la propiedad .text

Comment: yy... como pongo eso en el apartado de usuario? con `.send_Keys(Keys.Control + "v")` o con `email` / `emailInput.get` ?

Comment: Pues ya tienes el usuario guardado en user_name, simplemente escribelo. tuWebElement.sendKeys(user_name)

Comment: okay, muchas gracias

Answer (score -1):

que librerias se ocupan para driver.find_element_by_name("q").send_keys(Keys.CONTROL+ "v") lo necesito gracias

Comment: Si lo que tienes es una duda por favor crea una nueva pregunta o en su defecto, utiliza la sección de comentarios la cual esta destinada para dicho fin. Las respuestas deben [incluir una solución al problema](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) o guiar para resolverlo, no deben agregar más cuestionamientos.